# Why does Linux kaslr also randomize physical addresses?

Tags: linux-kernel, aslr

This is looks strange because after mmu enabled we operate with virtual addresses and don't use physical addresses.

Comment: I don't know the answer for sure but if I had to guess, it could be some mitigation against DMA-based attacks. It would make it hard to know where certain kernel data structures are.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that it is a hardening of the kernel.
Suppose that an attacker is able to corrupt a PTE.
If the physical location of the kernel is always known, then the attacker can immediately remap the page onto a suitable physical location and get code execution as a privileged user.

I think 'protection from DMA-capable devices' is not a valid answer.
If a malicious DMA-capable device has access to all of the physical memory, e.g. no protection through IOTLB, then the device can scrape memory and immediately find where the kernel is located in physical memory.